# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function - JQuery load() not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't know what's wrong.
I've tried the slim and the normal version of JQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#maker").change(function(){
               var act = $('input:radio[name=accountType]:checked').val();
               if (act == "true")
               {
                    $("#complementary").load("eu.hmtl")
               };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible that $("#complementary") selector is not returning any results?

Comment: You have two instances of jQuery. I recommend having only one. The _slim_ version will **not** include `.load()` so use the full version only

Comment: @ArunSelin shouldn't matter if there's any matching elements or not.

Comment: print $("#complementary") and check if it contains load function

Comment: correct the file extension as eu.html in the .load function

Comment: You have added jquery twice try to remove <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 .It may help

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just had to take off one of the JQuery instances in the head of the HTML.